# invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='? python

Tags: jupyter-notebook

```
array = dataset.values
X = array[:,0:4]
Y = array[:,4]
validation_size = 0.20
seed = 6
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split[X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed]
```

I am on my first machine learning class and this error popped up. I am trying to assign the value of

```
test_size
```

&

```
random_state
```

to

```
validation_size
```

&

```
seed
```

and as soon as I hit run this error popped.
Need help. I am using jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses instead of brackets:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)
```

Comment: 'function' object is not subscriptable = This is the error that occured model_selection.train_test_split[X, Y, validation_size, seed] = This is the highlited text

Comment: If you're using [scikit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) then you need to use parentheses instead of brackets since `train_test_split` is a function:`X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)`